# How to handle foreach loop Powershell two times?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I have foreach loop inside foreach loop. I do some string process and mapping a file with specific string.
I use messagebox to let user know which file is match or not. I tried this, it works, but the messsagebox show 6 times but It supposed to be 3 times. Anyone can help me please. Thank you.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Process = "D:\Pro"
$AllFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Process\*.pro -File | ForEach-Object {$_.BaseName.Substring(45)}
$Selected = @("XY11WWOLAT601A1ABA", "XY11WWOLAT601APABA", "XY11WWOLAT601ZHABA") | ForEach-Object {$_.Substring(2,13)}

foreach ($job in $AllFiles)
{
    
     $JobSplit = $job -split "_"
     $Name =  [string]::Concat($JobSplit)

     foreach ($SW in $Selected)
     {
          if ($SW -like "*$Name")
          {
               [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $SW`nNOT available.","[Error]" , "OK", "Error")
          
          }
          else {

               [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $SW`nAvailable.","[Info]" , "OK", "Info")     
          }
     }         
}
```

This is the `AllFiles` sample:
`123456789A_A2E9D28DA533_20200702045123_XX_ABC11WWOLAT601_A1.pro`
`123456789A_A2E9D28DA533_20200702011155_XX_ABC11WWOLAT601_ZH.pro`

Comment: Sorry, but the meeage box shows only 3 times. Are tou sure you've got only one file in d:\pro ? Reload your PowerShell.

Comment: no, I have more than file in the `d:\pro` @JPBlanc

Comment: So, for each file the message appears 3 times.

Comment: But it appears 6 times @JPBlanc

Comment: @JPBlanc it will appears this message 5 times: `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $SW`nAvailable.","[Info]" , "OK", "Info") ` 
Then this message 1 time: `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $SW`nNOT available.","[Error]" , "OK", "Error")`

Comment: Thats no the cas when I run it with one file.

Comment: @SBR Such a discussion is useless. Tell us how to exactly reproduce your problem by a minimal example. Then we can have a look into this exact problem. So, as you provide us just one filename (which is good and hopefully sufficient), then describe/discuss the problem that is caused by this one filename. Long story short: Which messages/errors do you get, if you have only this one file in `D:\pro`?

Comment: This just a matter of simple troubleshooting: in the outer loop place `write-host 'job:' $job` and in the inner loop place: `write-host 'SW:' $SW`. It should give you hint in what is different then you expected.

Comment: There was some inconsistencies in your initial post... Either you want a result per file, which based on your 2 file sample, mean there would be 2 results or you want 1 result per item in `$Selected` to indicate whether or not they are available. I assumed the former in my answer. Just leave a comment to my answer if I misunderstood your objective here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a second loop here.

There are some inconsistencies in your question though.

You say :

> I use messagebox to let user know which file is match or not

Then

> it works, but the messsagebox show 6 times but It supposed to be 3 times

And provide a 2 filename sample as reference

> 123456789A_A2E9D28DA533_20200702045123_XX_ABC11WWOLAT601_A1.pro
> 123456789A_A2E9D28DA533_20200702011155_XX_ABC11WWOLAT601_ZH.pro

If you want 1 message box per file to state whether or not it match the string, then you'll end up with **2** message box. Not 3, not 6.

Now, to your actual problem.
You only need to loop through all the files one by one and validate whether or not they are part of `$Selected`. That second part does not require a second loop. Rather, we'll determine if the filename is a match using the `.where` method.

```
foreach ($Job in $AllFiles) {
    $Selection = $Selected.Where( { $_ -like "*$Job" },'first')
    
    if ($Selection.count -gt 0) {
        [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $($Selection[0])`nNOT available.", "[Error]" , "OK", "Error")
    }
    else {
        [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $Job`nAvailable.", "[Info]" , "OK", "Info")     
    }
}
```

If I got this the wrong way around and your really wanted 3 message box, thus 1 message box per item in `$Selected` rather than 1 message box per file, then you just need to change the `foreach` loop for this one :

```
foreach ($SW in $Selected) {
    $Selection = $AllFiles.Where( { $SW -like "*$_" }, 'first')

    if ($Selection.Count -eq 1) {
        [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $SW`nNOT available.", "[Error]" , "OK", "Error")
    }
    else {
        [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $SW`nAvailable.", "[Info]" , "OK", "Info")     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sage Pourpre appreciated! But it only show the messagebox once the selection match, it will not show the messagebox once the selection not match. My expectation the messagebox can show both the condition

Comment: Thank you @Sage.
I did some modification from your answer, then It works as my expectation. Thank you so much. Really appreciated! 
`
 `foreach ($sel in $Selection)
{
     $Files = $AllFiles.Where( { $_ -like "*$sel*" })
     if ($Files.count -gt 0) {
         [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $($Files[0])`nNOT available.", "[Error]" , "OK", "Error")
     }
     else {
         [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $sel Available.", "[Info]" , "OK", "Info")     
     }
}`

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding how nested loops work.
ForEach data object in the outloop, process the data object in then inner loop.

Example:

```
1..3 | 
ForEach {
"`n *** Processing outloop $PSItem *** `n"
    'a','b','c' | 
    ForEach {
        "Processing innerloop $PSItem"
    }
}
# Results
<#
*** Processing outloop 1 *** 

Processing innerloop a
Processing innerloop b
Processing innerloop c

*** Processing outloop 2 *** 

Processing innerloop a
Processing innerloop b
Processing innerloop c

*** Processing outloop 3 *** 

Processing innerloop a
Processing innerloop b
Processing innerloop c
#>
```

So... as for your code...

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Process  = "D:\Pro"

# ForEach #1
$AllFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Process\*.pro -File | 
ForEach-Object {$_.BaseName.Substring(45)}

# ForEach #2
$Selected = @("XY11WWOLAT601A1ABA", "XY11WWOLAT601APABA", "XY11WWOLAT601ZHABA") | 
ForEach-Object {$_.Substring(2,13)}


<#
ForEach #3 that use the results of ForEach #1
This is the outer ForLoop
This will process for each data object
So, whatever the count of $Allfiles is each must be process X times
#>
foreach ($job in $AllFiles)
{
     "Processing job $job in the outer loop"
     $JobSplit = $job -split "_"
     $Name =  [string]::Concat($JobSplit)

    <#
    ForEach #4 that use the results of ForEach #2
    This is the inner ForLoop
    This will process 3 times for each data object in the outerloop
    Each much be processed for each data object in $AllFiles.
    #>
     foreach ($SW in $Selected)
     {
        "Processing SW $SW in the inner loop"
          if ($SW -like "*$Name")
          {
               [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $SW`nNOT available.","[Error]" , "OK", "Error")
          
          }
          else {

               [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This SW: $SW`nAvailable.","[Info]" , "OK", "Info")     
          }
     }         
}
```

Comment: @posanote thank you for your advice. But it still appear 6 times. In the command it shows this `OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK`

Comment: my expectation it only appear 3 times because I only has 3 `$Selected` array.

Comment: No worries. You will only get 3 if you only have 1 data object from $AllFiles. So, if you only 3 responses, you don't want to use a nested loop.